# My Pokemon disappear

Tags: pokemon-go

Why do my Pokemon disappear? Every time I get out of and then come back to the Pokemon Go app, I have to log in again (IDK why?). When I log back in, my caught Pokemon have disappeared. Is this supposed to happen or is something wrong?

Comment: Probably server connection problems

Comment: I've heard of people having this issue when they sign into the app using a Pokémon Trainer Club account (rather than a Google account) while the servers are having issues. Are you signing in with that type of account?

Answer (score 2):

The commenters on this question are correct. I have experienced the same thing and my solution has been to shut down the app (in task manager for android, and the iPhone equivalent by double-tapping the home button and swiping) and restarting it. You may not be successful at the moment even after several tries however, because of the volume of traffic their servers are currently supporting (or in your case and mine, not supporting)